# AWS lambda is not able to find the class that is given in handler

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I wrote a simple java program that will take a Person object in JSON format and return a string message. The dependencies are being maintained by Maven and below are all the dependencies that have been included in the pom.xml

`aws-lambda-java-core`
`maven-shade-plugin`

I have included `maven-shade-plugin` as plugin also apart from the dependency and ran the maven build with the goal `package shade:shade`. After the successful build I deployed the `app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar` file into the lambda function that I created, when I test this function I am getting below response and was not able to resolve the issue.

`{ "errorMessage": "Class not found: com.abc.nimbus.Handler", "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" }`

below is the class that is implementing the `RequestHandler` interface

```
package com.abc.nimbus;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Person, String>{

    public String handleRequest(Person input, Context context) {
        return "Got the message";
    }
}
```

and the value of the handler of the lambda function is
`com.abc.nimbus.Handler::handleRequest`

Comment: Could you provide a code that reproduces your error?

Comment: @statut added the code

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can check, based on my not so extense experience:

1. Check the size of the package uploaded. I have had that error when I was not properly building the maven project, and when I realized I checked the file in S3 it was less than 1MB, when (in my case) is usually around 70MB. So it was not properly built.
2. Personally I am using eclipse:eclipse as goal, maybe you can try that, see if it works.
3. Check that lambda is pointing to the right version of your packaged code and if any VPC should be configured.

I hope it helps.

Comment: code's packaged size is less than 10 MB so i dont think there is a need to upload it to S3 or somewhere else. I didnt understand what you meant by right version, there is only one version of the code for that lambda .

Comment: I program with Java on Eclipse so I use the Eclipse plugin to upload the lambda to S3. Then I run the code (in my case, calling my API), then check for logs. In the past I have found your error when my uploading of the code was done with the wrong version of the code (different git branches, or the packaging was not taking ALL the libraries so the project was too light). I thought it was worth a shot to comment that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

verify if the application has built properly. You can also use 'install shade:shade' command to build the project.
Make sure that the configuration in aws console points to the exact class and method of the Lambda code.